# setting up bloomberg api for python

Tags: programming, bloomberg

I am trying to configure bloomberg api in python. I have used pip to install the api, i also downloaded the BloombergWindowsSDK.

I am not sure where to go from here. Can i please get a step by step detail explanation of how to make connect to Bloomberg via python. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have bloomberg api access, but I am seeing a nice package and step by step interface here.

https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python

Answer (score 1):

Very user-friendly package here. If you are using Python 3, look in Issues for tips on compatible versions.

https://github.com/bpsmith/tia